# Getting managed service principal id, without AD access

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I'm looking for my VSTS deployment agent service principal to get the Object ID of a managed service principal (created by Data Factory V2).

It needs this for assigning ACL's in data lake store.

However as far as I can tell, it requires Read Permission on Azure AD.

I wish to avoid granting it read permission if possible, to follow the 'least privilege' mantra.

For non-managed service principals, I allow the deployment agent to manage service principals it has created (thus not needing full read access). However I suspect the fact that the service principals are *managed* by Azure it is unlikely I'll be able to give the deployment agent any ownership over the managed service principal (however I'm working with AD admins to see if there is a way).

I've tried everything I can think of mixing and matching Azure RM data factory v2 powershell modules and Azure AD modules.

Is it possible to get the id without Azure AD read access? Or a novel workaround (I'm considering a constrained Web API wrapper)?

Comment: As I known, there is no way to access the ObjectId of sp without AAD read access. Even you can consider use <client>--<WebAPI>--<AAD>, but the WebAPI still needs directory read permission.

Comment: Thanks @WayneYang-MSFT my thinking is that I can grant the WebAPI SP AAD access and monitor it more easily than the same with the deployment agent (which will be doing all sorts).